# Error while switching windows using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've written a Ruby script to automate some user operations using IE. 
I'm using Selenium Web Driver for IE. Below is my code.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie

first_window = browser.window_handle
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element(:id=> 'outerFrame'))
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element(:id=> 'innerFrame'))

table_rows = browser.find_element(:id=> 'AllItems').find_element(:tag_name=> 'table').find_elements(:tag_name=> 'tr')
count_cell = table_rows.at(table_rows.length-1).find_elements(:tag_name=> 'td').at(1).find_element(:tag_name=> 'a')
count_cell.click

sleep(5)

all_windows = browser.window_handles
new_window = browser.window_handles.last

browser.switch_to.window(new_window)

btn = browser.find_element(:id=> 'btn_export')
btn.click
```

At one point, after clicking a button, a new page is opened. Now, when I try to switch to the new window, I get the following error.

> C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in 'initialize': No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it. - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 5555 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in 'open'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in 'block in connect'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:75:in 'timeout'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in 'connect'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in 'do_start'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in 'start'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1375:in 'request'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in 'response_for'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:58:in
>   'request'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in
>   'call'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:664:in
>   'raw_execute'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:642:in
>   'execute'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:216:in
>   'switchToWindow'
>           from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.48.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:81:in
>   'window'
>           from script.rb:18:in ''

I tried my bit to resolve the error, by modifying firewall and added rules for port 5555. Even then issue persists. I found some already exsting questions on this, but most of them are related to Java or .Net. How can I resolve this error? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: does the same thing happen on chrome or firefox?

Comment: The site is IE specific. It does not open on other browsers.

Comment: before clicking and going to new window save the wnidow handle of 1st webpage then click and after your operations are done use saved window handle to come back to original screen

Comment: I am doing the same currently. "count_cell.click" is the step, where it opens a new page.

Comment: If you could provide a bit of html/css/js to reproduce the issue it might help us debug. The most simple example that can reproduce it.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484161/unable-to-run-selenium-script-on-ie

Comment: did you try [this approach](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/4-work-with-multiple-windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ruby expert, but I have seen similar problems happening. I have a Python-ic solution. All you need to do is Ruby-fy the code. https://gist.github.com/ab9-er/08c3ce7d2d5cdfa94bc7

```
def change_window(browser):
    """
    Simple window switcher without the need of playing with ids.
    @param browser: Current browser instance
    """
    curr = browser.current_window_handle
    all_handles = browser.window_handles
    for handle in list(set([curr]) - set(all_handles)):
        return browser.switch_to_window(handle)
```

Comment: For what it is worth, the Ruby code he is using is the appropriate method for switching to a window in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching back to the top level browsing context before switching to a new window.

```
browser.switch_to.default_content
current_window = browser.window_handle
new_window = browser.window_handles.find { |win| win != current_window }
browser.switch_to.window(new_window)
```

It should do this implicitly, so if it isn't, it's likely a bug. If this works, please let me know so I can see if we need to file a bug report.

Comment: Can you verify that there are more than one windows open? And can you verify this code works with Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Also, I was reminded that the window handles aren't returned with any order, so I modified the code I provided.